# Run remote app on remote pc but show in my local pc [windows only]

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

I have software to run in Windows remote pc , it's installed in remote pc but I want to run in remote pc and display on my local pc.

I looked in psexec but couldn't get way. Using windows server , I have username password of remote desktop.

More clarification:- I have installed an windows app in server , I have many user clients having own windows pc. I make each user access same app only display of app on their local computer. I keep one login on server and it's username password kept with all clients. I prepared to access server drive with login password on windows explorer sharing to all users. I can't give remote desktop access as whole but only for that app?

Comment: This question is here off topic. You may ask on [https://superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [https://serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com). Why not using an RDP-Connection?

Comment: Use linux instead with putty and xming?

Comment: @mklement0 yes GUI application I want to share , should run in server and my client only access it's display and control.